# Is there anyway to detect a user's connection to its profile? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, reddit

So  I've been experimenting and tinkering with discord.js and node.js and a friend of mine created a discord server for his subreddit and he only wanted people who is in on the subreddit OR who has a reddit account. I knew for a fact that Discord had the `user.fetchProfile()` method but they removed it and there is no sign of they will return it in to the API. So I came here to ask: **Is there any way to detect/fetch a discord user's profile has a connection to it(reddit, xbox, ps4 etc.)?**

Comment: `user.fetchProfile` was not a thing it was `<ClientUser>.fetchProfile()`, which only got the bot's profile, and real bots couldn't have connections, as such this was only a thing with self bots, and discord has removed the ability for self bots, so that's why they removed the fetchProfile function along side other self bot only commands. So no you can't get connections anymore, you can use the reddit api like rez suggested

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `REDDIT API`, You'll need to research more because I'm not familiar with this function...
Hopefully, someone else can help.